# Why does $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^k X_{f_i^N}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On page 70 of Mumford's *The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes second*, expanded edition (GTM 358), in the proof of Lemma 2, the author said

> On the other hand, we have $$X = \bigcup_{i=1}^k X_{f_i}  = \bigcup_{i=1}^k X_{f_i^N}.$$

I don't know why this is true. Does this come from the previous fact "$b_i' f_j^N - b_j'f_i^N =0$"?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is $X_f$ the set of prime ideals that do not contain $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more general result which applies directly to your problem.

> > Let $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$. Then for $f,g\in A$, $D(f) = D(g)$ iff $\sqrt{(f)} = \sqrt{(g)}$. Proof:

If $D(f) = D(g)$ then a prime $P$ doesn't contain $f$ iff it doesn't contain $g$. Negating, a prime $P$ contains $f$ iff it contains $g$.  The set of all primes containing an element is its radical. Hence taking the intersection over all these primes gives that $\sqrt{(f)} = \sqrt{(g)}$.

Conversely if $\sqrt{(f)} = \sqrt{(g)}$ let $P$ be a prime such that $f \notin P$. Then $f \in \sqrt{(f)} = \sqrt{(g)}$ implies there is some $n$, $h\in A$ for which $f^n = gh$. Then $g \notin P$ too otherwise $f^n \in P \implies f \in P$. Hence $P \in D(g)$. Similarly we conclude $D(g) \subseteq D(f)$, hence $D(f) = D(g)$.

Comment: One doesn't need this result. One only needs $D(f)=D(f^n)$, which is a direct consequence of the definitions (namely, of $D(f)$ and of a prime ideal).

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, I agree one does not need the full strength of this result for the problem. However, I was just trying to show the OP that what he wants comes from a more general result.

Answer (score 1):

You should mention what everything is, but assuming it's some scheme (or even a locally ringed space) and $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ you should think of $X_f$ as being the set of points of $X$ where $f$ does not vanish. Vanishing means you map to zero under the homomorphism
$$
\mathcal{O}_X(X) \to \mathcal{O}_{X, p} \to \mathcal{O}_{X, p}/\mathfrak{m}_{X, p} = \kappa(p)
$$
which "evaluates" functions at $p$. The target is a field, so if $f^n$ vanishes then $f$ certainly does.